# unblurring using FFT correction

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

i am trying to deblur using the following code.

```html
G1 = im2double(imread('C:\Users\adhil\Desktop\matlab pics\test.JPG'));
figure, imshow (G1);

h_1 = fspecial( 'gaussian', [130 221] , 1.0 );
% Fourier Transform of 2D Gaussian 
H_1 = fftshift(h_1);
H_1 = fft2(H_1); 
H_1 = ifftshift(H_1); 

F_1a = zeros(size(G1));

for idx = 1 : size(G1, 3)
    G_1 = fftshift(G1(:,:,idx));
    G_1 = fft2(G_1); 
    G_1 = ifftshift(G_1);

    tmp = G_1 ./ H_1; 
    tmp = ifftshift(tmp); 
    tmp = ifft2(tmp); 
    tmp = fftshift(tmp); 
    F_1a(:,:,idx) = tmp;
end

figure, imshow (F_1);
```

but this is the result.

[image]

is there anyway i can optimize the code to unblurr the image properly? please advise.

Comment: You're getting that because (1) A Gaussian blur was not applied to that image to blur it and so reversing the blur isn't giving you the right results, (2) Straight up deconvolution is usually ill-posed and doesn't result in unique solutions, even without any noise: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Deconvolution.html.  Look at the duplicate post I provided. If that doesn't help, look on the MathWorks page on all deconvolution methods that are shipped with the Image Processing Toolbox: http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/image-restoration-deblurring.html. Hope you find something.

Comment: I wasn't given the PSF that originally created the distortion. is it possible to do blind deconvolution in the frequency domain, to rectify the results?

Comment: Yes it is. You've asked this question at least 5 times. Your latest question had an answer that makes reference to it.

Comment: yeah ive used all those methods, but i was unable to recreate a viable result, however, i did get marginally good results using the deconvblind using a reconstructed true psf. just wanted to know how i can optimize the results